# Postgres ratio_to_report function

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Can someone indicate me how to install analytic functions and especially the **ratio_to_report** function in a Postgres database ?

I have tried to search in the postgres supplied modules but I didn't see the module that contains the function.

Comment: I believe this function is Oracle specific. You could however implement the same behaviour using simple math and `sum()` function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **[RATIO_TO_REPORT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions124.htm)**
>
> RATIO_TO_REPORT is an analytic function. **It computes the ratio of a value to the sum of a set of values. If expr evaluates to null, then the ratio-to-report value also evaluates to null.**

You  don't need importing specific function at all. Postgresql equivalent using windowed `SUM`:

```
SELECT ID, val, 1.0 * val / NULLIF(SUM(val) OVER(),0) AS ratio_to_report
FROM tab
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d0972/4/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦══════╦═════════════════════╗
║ id  ║ val  ║   ratio_to_report   ║
╠═════╬══════╬═════════════════════╣
║  1  ║  10  ║ 0.16666666666666666 ║
║  2  ║  10  ║ 0.16666666666666666 ║
║  3  ║  20  ║ 0.3333333333333333  ║
║  4  ║  20  ║ 0.3333333333333333  ║
╚═════╩══════╩═════════════════════╝
```

---

To simulate `PARTITION BY` you could use:

```
SELECT ID, val, category,
    1.0 * val / NULLIF(SUM(val) OVER(PARTITION BY category),0) AS ratio_to_report
FROM tab
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/de23b/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦══════╦═══════════╦═════════════════╗
║ id  ║ val  ║ category  ║ ratio_to_report ║
╠═════╬══════╬═══════════╬═════════════════╣
║  1  ║  10  ║ a         ║ 0.25            ║
║  2  ║  10  ║ a         ║ 0.25            ║
║  3  ║  20  ║ a         ║ 0.5             ║
║  4  ║  20  ║ b         ║ 1               ║
╚═════╩══════╩═══════════╩═════════════════╝
```