# How do I calculate percentages within group by in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that groups a company's name, size and revenue. This is my query:

```
with Test as
(select
id.name as Company
,CASE WHEN li.segment = 'Large' then 'Large Cap'
      WHEN li.segment = 'Medium' then 'Mid Cap'
      WHEN li.segment = 'Small' then 'Small Cap' else NULL end as Size
,sum(ia.amount) as Revenue
from base.company_rev ia
join base.company_detail id on id.company_account_id = ia.company_account_id
left join base.product_issued li on li.product_id = ia.product_id
where 1 = 1
and ia.create_date::date between '2018-05-01' and '2018-05-31'
group by id.name, li.segment
order by 1, 2, 3)

 select * 
 from Test
 group by company, size, revenue
 order by 1, 2, 3
```

How do I add a percentage of revenue that each company's size is attributed to? I want to do it based on the dollar amount within the size groupings.

Ex.

```
Company A...Large Cap...15m = 60% (15/25)
Company A...Mid Cap...10m = 40% (10/25)
```

Comment: [Postgres ratio_to_report function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976390/postgres-ratio-to-report-function)

Comment: Why are you aggregating on the company twice?

Comment: `ORDER BY` in a subquery (here in your `WITH` clause) is superfluous. The `GROUP BY` in your main query is also superfluous, because it contains all columns, thus doing exactly nothing. At last: It is considered bad style to use positional `ORDER BY`. Use names instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a window function, namely `SUM() OVER()`.

```
with test as
(
  select
    id.name as company
    ,case when li.segment = 'Large' then 'Large Cap'
          when li.segment = 'Medium' then 'Mid Cap'
          when li.segment = 'Small' then 'Small Cap' 
          else null end as size
    ,sum(ia.amount) as revenue
  from base.company_rev ia
  join base.company_detail id on id.company_account_id = ia.company_account_id
  left join base.product_issued li on li.product_id = ia.product_id
  where 1 = 1
  and ia.create_date::date between date '2018-05-01' and date '2018-05-31'
  group by id.name, li.segment
)
select
  company, 
  size, 
  revenue,
  revenue / sum(revenue) over (partition by company) * 100 as percentage
from test
order by company, size, revenue;
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**(ia.amount/sum(ia.amount))*100 as Percentage**